# MySQL Java Connection with my application

Tags: java, mysql

the following is my code for the Java class connection to mysql server, i need to see if there is any suggestion to make it better.

this class not making the connection, it just control transactions, selecting, updating & deleting.

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import core.*;

public class CruesDataAccessor {

   private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
   private PreparedStatement updateStatement;
   private PreparedStatement insertStatement;
   private PreparedStatement deleteStatement;
   private ResultSet dataResultSet;
   private Connection connection;
   private Vector<String> columensDataTypes;
   private Vector<String> columensNames;
   private Vector<Object> queryDataVtr;
   private Vector<Object> filteredColNames;
   private int count = 0;
   private Vector<Integer> colsWidth;
   private String tablename;

   // the constructor
   public CruesDataAccessor(Connection conn) {
       connection = conn;
       try {
       } catch (Exception e) {
           myError(e, "1");
       }
   }

   // setting connection
   public void setConnection(Connection conn) {
       connection = conn;
       try {
       } catch (Exception e) {
           myError(e, "2");
       }
   }

   // used to get the data based on a mysql statement
   public void clearMe(){
       columensDataTypes.removeAllElements();
       columensNames.removeAllElements();
       queryDataVtr.removeAllElements();
       filteredColNames.removeAllElements();
       colsWidth.removeAllElements();
   }
   public Vector<?> getData(String sqlStmnt) {
       // remove illegal characters from the mysql statement
       sqlStmnt = Declare.replaceIllegalChars(sqlStmnt);
       //sqlStmnt = sqlStmnt.toLowerCase();

       // used to fill the names of the columns
       filteredColNames = new Vector<Object>();
       queryDataVtr = new Vector<Object>();
       columensNames = new Vector<String>();

       // used to fill column widths
       colsWidth = new Vector<Integer>();
       try {
           count = 0;
           // a prepare a MySQL statement
           preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStmnt);
           // execute the query and get the result
           dataResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sqlStmnt);
           // get the types of the data
           ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = dataResultSet.getMetaData();
           count = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
           columensDataTypes = new Vector<String>();
           // parse the data and fill the necessary variables
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               columensNames.addElement(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1));
               setTableName(resultSetMetaData.getTableName(1));
               setFilteredColumnNames(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1));
               setColsWidth(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1).length());
               String dataType = resultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName(i + 1);

               if (dataType.indexOf("String") != -1) {
                   columensDataTypes.add("string");
               } else if (dataType.indexOf("Date") != -1 ||
                          dataType.indexOf("Timestamp") != -1) {
                   columensDataTypes.add("date");
               } else if ((dataType.indexOf("BigDecimal") != -1) ||
                          (dataType.indexOf("Integer") != -1) ||
                          (dataType.indexOf("Long") != -1)) {
                   columensDataTypes.add("number");
               } else {
                   columensDataTypes.add("string");
               }
           }

           // filling the information in a vector
           Vector<String> recordVtr;
           while (dataResultSet.next()) {
               recordVtr = new Vector<String>();
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   try {
                       recordVtr.addElement(dataResultSet.getString(i + 1));
                   } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                       recordVtr.addElement("");
                   }
               }
               queryDataVtr.add(recordVtr);
           }

           // closing
           try {
               dataResultSet.close();
               dataResultSet = null;
           } catch (Exception exx) {
               myError(exx, "3");
               dataResultSet = null;
           }
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           try {
               dataResultSet.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
           }
           myError(exx, "4");
           dataResultSet = null;
       }

       preparedStatement = null; //
       return queryDataVtr;
   }

   // get the column names in a vector
   public Vector<String> getColumnNames() {
       return columensNames;
   }

   // filter the column names
   public void setFilteredColumnNames(String str) {
       boolean found = false;
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
           if (str.charAt(i) == '_') {
               filteredColNames.add(str.substring(i + 1, str.length()));
               found = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (!found) {
           filteredColNames.add(str);
       }
   }

   // get the types of the column fields
   public Vector<String> getDataTypes() {
       return this.columensDataTypes;
   }

   // get the filtered column names
   public Vector<?> getfilteredColumNames() {
       return filteredColNames;
   }

   // get the column counts
   public int getColumnCount() {
       return count;
   }

   // set default column widths
   public void setColsWidth(int width) {
       colsWidth.add(new Integer(100));
   }

   // get column widths
   public Vector<Integer> getColumnsWidth() {
       return colsWidth;
   }

   // used to update the database with an SQL statement
   public synchronized boolean UpdateDB(String sql) {
       sql = Declare.replaceIllegalChars(sql);
       //sql = sql.toLowerCase();
       int result = 0;
       try {
           updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
           result = updateStatement.executeUpdate();
           updateStatement = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "5");
           Declare.exCounter += 1;
      //     sexx.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Erro: "+sexx);
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           System.out.println("Erro: "+exx);
          // myError(exx, "6");
       }
       if (result == 1) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   // used to insert in the database with an SQL statement
   public synchronized boolean InsertDB(String sql) {
       sql = Declare.replaceIllegalChars(sql);
       int result = 0;
       try {
           insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
           result = insertStatement.executeUpdate();
           insertStatement = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           System.out.println("Erro: "+sexx);
           myError(sexx, "7");
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "8");
           System.out.println("Erro: "+exx);
       }
       if (result == 1) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   // used to delete from the database with an SQL statement
   public synchronized boolean DeleteDB(String sql) {
       int result = 0;
       try {
           deleteStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
           result = deleteStatement.executeUpdate();
           deleteStatement = null; //
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "9");
           System.out.println("Erro: "+exx);
       }
       if (result == 1) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   public void setTableName(String tablename) {
       this.tablename = tablename;
   }

   public String getTableName() {
       return this.tablename;
   }

   // used to lock the table
   public synchronized boolean lockTable(String sql) {
       //sql = sql.toLowerCase();
       Statement stmt = null;
       try {
           stmt = connection.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           stmt = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "14");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "15");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // used to unlock the table
   public synchronized boolean unlockTable(String sql) {
       //sql = sql.toLowerCase();
       Statement stmt = null;
       try {
           stmt = connection.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           stmt = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "16");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "17");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // use to start aut commit mode
   public synchronized boolean initAutoCommit() {
       try {
           if(connection.getAutoCommit()){
               System.out.println("SetAutoCommit = false");
              connection.setAutoCommit(false);
           }
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "18");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "19");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // use to begin the transaction
   public synchronized boolean beginTransaction() {
       Statement stmt = null;
       Declare.exCounter = 0;
       try {
           stmt = connection.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate("START TRANSACTION;");
           System.out.println("START TRANSACTION");
           stmt = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "20");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "21");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // used to end the transaction
   public synchronized boolean endTransaction() {
       try {
           connection.commit();
           System.out.println("Transaction Commited");
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
          // myError(sexx, "22");
           System.out.println(sexx);
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "23");
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }

   // used to rollback the transaction
   public synchronized boolean rollBack() {
       try {
           connection.rollback();
           System.out.println("Transaction Rolled Back");
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "24");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "25");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // used to modify the language
   public synchronized boolean modifyLanguage(String sql) {
       Statement stmt = null;
       try {
           stmt = connection.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           stmt = null; //
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "26");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "27");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   // a general error routine
   private void myError(Exception c, String no) {
       Declare.exCounter+= 1;
       c.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

scanned your code, good to go, just one thing-- by Convention Java methods start with lower case. 
So, the method "**UpdateDB()**" better suit **updateDb()** or **updateDatabase()**